# Alternative writing Select query Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have below `select` query where i am using `OR` condition to seperate  two conditions. As you can see i am checking field `EXORID` twice if it has value or if it is `null`. But i am thinking is there any other way where i can combine this two condition at once, something like `(EXORID = '2100' OR null)`.

```
    select * from ORD_TEST where (OID = '2100' and EXORID = '21096006')
    or (OID = '2100' and EXORID is null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange the logic:

```
where OID = '2100' and (EXORID = '21096006' or EXORID is null)
```

Comment: just wanted to know is ther any issue with performance here ? Because the query which i mentioned is running fine without performance issue, i have non unique index defined on EXORID and OID and my table has 80k rows

Comment: @Symonds . . . Not at all.  Some databases might optimize this form more easily.  Oracle has a good optimizer, so it shouldn't make a difference.  Well . . . hmmm . . . I could see one possible issue if you had an index on `(EXORID, OID)` rather than `(OID, EXORID)`.  But even in that case, I think Oracle would be fine.